# Does adf V2 support oracle pl/sql?

Tags: azure-data-factory

Does azure data factory copy activity supports oracle pl sql query?
The sample select statement is owrking but what about pl/sql programes

Comment: Can you provide examples of what you have done so far?  What is the query? What is the error? Have you tried a pl/sql procedure? You might find the answer you are looking for by just trying,


Please refer to
[How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
and
[create a Minimal, Complete, Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Hi,does my answer helps you? If so,would you please accept it? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the [official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-oracle#copy-activity-properties),copy activity only supports normal sql in the transactions. Pl sql is not supported by ADF connectors directly.

However,you could consider using [Custom Activity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/transform-data-using-dotnet-custom-activity#custom-activity) when you want to transform/process data in a way that isn't supported by Data Factory.

Please follow the details in this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/transform-data-using-dotnet-custom-activity#custom-activity).It is rely on the Azure Batch Job in the VM. In that Job,you could execute pl sql code block by python package `cx_Oracle`,please see this [detailed document](https://dzone.com/articles/execute-plsql-calls-with-python-and-cx-oracle).